# Property exception component:'jsgfGrammar'

Tags: java, eclipse, sphinx4

So I have been trying to start writing my own code for Sphinx4. I created my own grammar, config, and java file, all necessary for it to run, and used the code from the HelloWorld demo. However, when I ran the code, I received this error:

```
Problem configuring HelloWorld: Property exception component:'jsgfGrammar' property:'grammarLocation' - Can't locate resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/demo/hellowrld/
edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.InternalConfigurationException: Can't locate resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/demo/hellowrld/
Property exception component:'jsgfGrammar' property:'grammarLocation' - Can't locate resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/demo/hellowrld/
edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.InternalConfigurationException: Can't locate resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/demo/hellowrld/

at edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.ConfigurationManagerUtils.getResource(ConfigurationManagerUtils.java:483)
```

followed by more edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props that are missing apparently.

When I go to the project folder where the demos are, there aren't any files there, so I am not sure if there are files I am just missing or aren't included. Everything is in the same workspace folder as well.

Would anyone have any idea as to why my program isn't running? I need this baseline to work properly so I can write my own code.

Also any references to tutorial videos, links or documents to help with Sphinx4 would be greatly appreciated. I have seen a video from Puneet and Sharing is Caring on YouTube. The Sphinx site isn't that helpful in terms of starting because they mainly discuss the writing the code in manually, which was confusing.

Comment: You are trying very old sources, you need to follow the tutorial http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialsphinx4. There are existing demos available - dialog and transcriber. Its better to start with transcriber.

Comment: By dialog and transcriber, what do you mean?

Comment: I am not as familiar with things like Gradle. Are these java extensions or programs?

Comment: You have a good chance to learn more.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Property exception component:'wsjLoader'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33688870/property-exception-componentwsjloader)