# Sphinx4 can't locate resource

Tags: speech-recognition, cmusphinx, sphinx4

I am working on a speech recognition project using sphinx 4. Just tell me why I am getting this error. I had researched at every possible platform but my problem remains unsolved. I have placed all the related files (grammar, helloworld.xml) correctly. This error comes at the recognizer part in the program. Please anyone can help me?

```
Problem configuring HelloWorld: Property Exception component:'jsgfGrammar' property:'grammarLocation' - Can't locate resource:/demo.sphinx.helloworld.HelloWorld
Property Exception component:'jsgfGrammar' property:'grammarLocation' - Can't locate resource:/demo.sphinx.helloworld.HelloWorld
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.ValidatingPropertySheet.getResource(ValidatingPropertySheet.java:372)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.jsapi.JSGFGrammar.newProperties(JSGFGrammar.java:250)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.ConfigurationManager.lookup(ConfigurationManager.java:214)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.ValidatingPropertySheet.getComponent(ValidatingPropertySheet.java:403)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.flat.FlatLinguist.newProperties(FlatLinguist.java:169)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.ConfigurationManager.lookup(ConfigurationManager.java:214)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.ValidatingPropertySheet.getComponent(ValidatingPropertySheet.java:403)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.decoder.search.SimpleBreadthFirstSearchManager.newProperties(SimpleBreadthFirstSearchManager.java:183)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.ConfigurationManager.lookup(ConfigurationManager.java:214)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.ValidatingPropertySheet.getComponent(ValidatingPropertySheet.java:403)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.decoder.Decoder.newProperties(Decoder.java:71)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.ConfigurationManager.lookup(ConfigurationManager.java:214)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.ValidatingPropertySheet.getComponent(ValidatingPropertySheet.java:403)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.recognizer.Recognizer.newProperties(Recognizer.java:93)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.ConfigurationManager.lookup(ConfigurationManager.java:214)
    at HelloWorld.main(Jarvis.java:48)
```

Comment: You need to provide more data,.If a code snippet is not appropriate: starting/workin g directory, Also debuggers go a long way

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Property exception component:'wsjLoader'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33688870/property-exception-componentwsjloader)